# How to get grid nav bar to go right under a list view in xamarin forms app

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Hello I am working on a app in xamarin forms and my home screen UI looks like this:

[image]

how do I get the nav bar to go right under the flashcards card?

here's my xaml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="AppName.AppNameHome">
  <Grid RowSpacing="0" ColumnSpacing="0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ListView x:Name="listView" HasUnevenRows="true"  ItemSelected="OnItemSelected"> Grid.Row="0" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <ViewCell>
          <Frame Padding="0,0,0,8" BackgroundColor="#d2d5d7">
            <Frame.Content>
              <Frame Padding="15,15,15,15"   OutlineColor="Gray" BackgroundColor="White">
                <Frame.Content>
                  <StackLayout Padding="20,0,0,0"  Orientation="Horizontal">

                    <Image
                            HorizontalOptions="Start"
                            Source="{Binding Image}"/>
                    <Label 
                           HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                           Text="{Binding Name}"
                           FontFamily="OpenSans-Light"
                           FontSize="24"/>
                  </StackLayout>
                </Frame.Content>
              </Frame>
            </Frame.Content>
          </Frame>
        </ViewCell>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
  </ListView>
  <Grid Grid.Row="1" BackgroundColor="#eff3f6" Padding="0,0,0,0">
          <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"  VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
              <Button  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Image="books.png" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Clicked="OpenBooks" />
              <Button  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"  HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" BorderColor="Transparent" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Clicked="gotosettings" />
          </StackLayout>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

EDIT here's my c# code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using AppName.Math;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Plugin.Messaging;
using AppName.Flashcards;
using AppName.Science;

namespace AppName
{
    public partial class AppNameHome : ContentPage
    {
        public SchoolToolsHome()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


            var name = new List<Tools>
            {
                     new Tools("Internet", "web.png"),
                     new Tools("E-Mail", "email.png"),
                     new Tools("Math", "math.png"),
                     new Tools("Science", "sci.png"),
                     new Tools("Handwriting","handwriteing.png"),
                     new Tools("FlashCards", "flashcard.png"),
        };

            listView.ItemsSource = name;







        }

        void OnItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
        {

            var tools = e.SelectedItem as Tools;

            if (tools == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            ContentPage page = null;

            switch (tools.Name)
            {
                case "Math":
                    page = new MathPage();
                    break;
                case "Internet":
                    Device.OpenUri(new Uri("http://www.google.com"));
                    page = new AppNameHome();
                    break;

                case "E-Mail":
                    Device.OpenUri(new Uri("mailto:"));
                    page = new AppNameHome();

                    break;

                case "FlashCards":
                    page = new FlashCardHome();

                    break;


                case "Science":
                    page = new ScienceHome();

                    break;



                default:
                    page = new AppNameHome();
                    break;

            }

            ((ListView)sender).SelectedItem = null;
            page.BindingContext = tools;
            Navigation.PushAsync(page);
        }


                public void OpenBooks(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            switch (Device.OS)
            {
                case TargetPlatform.iOS:
                    Device.OpenUri(new Uri("itms-books:"));

                    break;


                case TargetPlatform.Android:
                    DependencyService.Get<OpenBookInterface>().openBooks();
                    break;
            }

        }


                public void gotosettings(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

                  Navigation.PushAsync(new SettingsPage());

        }

    }
}
```

any help would be amazing!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please show us some code from your `App.xaml.cs`? I am assuming, that you wrap your page in a `NavigationPage`, so I need to check, how you initialize the page. So please show me the constructor of your `App` class, where you set `MainPage = XXX`.

Comment: Robin-Manuel Thiel added the c# code please check the edit in the post :)

Comment: Oh, you added the code of the page, but I asked for the part where the whole app initializes the page. Please locate an `App.cs` or `App.xaml.cs` file in your project, where the line `MainPage = XXX`` appears. This is, what I need to see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried [ListView.Footer](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Xamarin.Forms.ListView.Footer/)?

> Gets or sets the string, binding, or view that will be displayed at
>   the bottom of the list view.

So you would have something like:

```
<ListView x:Name="listView" HasUnevenRows="true"  ItemSelected="OnItemSelected"> Grid.Row="0" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
    <ViewCell>
      <Frame Padding="0,0,0,8" BackgroundColor="#d2d5d7">
        <Frame.Content>
          <Frame Padding="15,15,15,15"   OutlineColor="Gray" BackgroundColor="White">
            <Frame.Content>
              <StackLayout Padding="20,0,0,0"  Orientation="Horizontal">

                <Image
                        HorizontalOptions="Start"
                        Source="{Binding Image}"/>
                <Label 
                       HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                       Text="{Binding Name}"
                       FontFamily="OpenSans-Light"
                       FontSize="24"/>
              </StackLayout>
            </Frame.Content>
          </Frame>
        </Frame.Content>
      </Frame>
    </ViewCell>
  </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
<ListView.Footer>
   <Grid BackgroundColor="#eff3f6" Padding="0,0,0,0">
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
         <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"  VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
           <Button  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Image="books.png" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Clicked="OpenBooks" />
           <Button  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"  HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" BorderColor="Transparent" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Clicked="gotosettings" />
       </StackLayout>
    </Grid>
</ListView.Footer>
</ListView>
```

Comment: List view footer did the trick but the stacklayout made all my icons go to the left once I took out the stacklayout it worked like a charm! Thank you so much!